# Computing complex number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

"Compute $(1 + i)^{1000}$.

So far I have: $(1+i)^{4 (2^2 5^3)} $ but I am not sure how to proceed. Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried computing $(1+i)^2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

${(i+1)}^{1000} = {({(i+1)}^{2})}^{500} = {(2i)}^{500} = {2}^{500}{i}^{500} = {2}^{500}{(i^2)}^{250} = {2}^{500}{(-1)}^{250}$

Comment: why can you make the jump from $((1+i)^2)^{500} = (2i)^{500}$ ?

Comment: @Ozera: ${(1+i)}^{2} = (1+i)(1+i) = 1^2+2i+i^2 = 1+2i-1 = 2i$

Comment: Shouldn't that $255$ be $250$?

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Ooops :) Thanks

Comment: @Ozera: Please note that in the original answer I wrote $255$ instead of $250$ (which essentially changes the answer from positive to negative).

Answer (score 7):

Powers of complex numbers are often easier in polar coordinates.  The absolute value of $(1+i)$ is $\sqrt{2}$, and its angle is $\pi/4$.  So the question becomes
$$(\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4})^{1000}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here, $\exp(z)$ stands for $e^z$

$$\begin{align}(1+i)^{1000}&=(\sqrt{2}(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}))^{1000} \\
&= \sqrt2^{1000}\exp(1000\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}i)\\
&=\sqrt{2}^{1000}\exp(250\pi i) \\
&=2^{500}(\cos(250\pi)+ i\sin(250\pi)) \\
&\text{For even multiples of $\pi$, $\cos \theta =1 , \sin \theta = 0$} \\
&=2^{500}(1+0)=2^{500}
\end{align}$$